# Python reading a file line by line and sending it to another Python script

Tags: python

Good day.

Today i was trying to practice python and Im trying to make a script that reads the lines from a file containing only numbers and using said numbers as a parameter in another Python script.

Here at work i sometimes need to execute a python script called Suspend.py, ever time i excute this scripit i must type the following information:

```
Suspend.py suspend telefoneNumber
```

I have to do this procedure many times during the day and i have to do this for every number on the list, it is usually a very long list. SO i though on trying to make things a little bit faster and creat a Python script myself.

Thing is a just started learning Python on my own i kinda suck at it, so i have no idea on how to do this.

In one file i have the following numbers:

```
87475899
87727856
87781681
87794922
87824499
88063188
88179211
88196532
88244043
88280924
88319531
88421427
88491113
```

I want python to be able to read line by line and send this number to another file script together with the word "suspend" on the previously said python script.

Comment: You want to call the other script with arguments from the lines?

Comment: Would it not be better just to put/import your "reading" function into that script you are passing numbers into or is there some restrictions out of your hands?

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, each number would be a new argument together with the word "suspend"

Comment: @MooingRawr Well the "Suspend.py"script is not mine and i dont how it works and Im pretty sure i can`t  change anything on it.

Comment: is that IPC? it seems strange to do this

Comment: @Alexandre Yau Well im not sure what IPC means but i have to connect into another computer to perform the "Suspend.py" script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
import subprocess

with open("file_with_numbers.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        subprocess.call(["python", "Suspend.py", "suspend", line.strip()])
```

Comment: Another question before i try executing this:

The Suspend script also has 2 outputs, he can output OK or error, if i execute this script will i be able to see these outputs?

Comment: Look into `subprocess.check_output`.